# Entity Framework filtering list within object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to filter a collection within an object in Entity Framework. I followed [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/tutorials/495287/selective-includes-with-entity-framework) example, which makes sense.

This is my resulting query:

```
var filteredClientEmp = context.Clients.Include(x => x.CompanyEmployee)
                .Where(c => c.HrPersonId == paId && c.CompanyEmployee.Any(e => e.EmployeeBirthday != null && e.EmpType == 2 &&
                                                                                    e.LeftCompany == null))
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    c,
                    CompanyEmployee =
                    c.CompanyEmployee.Where(e => e.EmployeeBirthday != null && e.EmpType == 2 &&
                                                 e.LeftCompany == null)
                })
                .ToList()
                .Select(pro => pro.c)
                .ToList();

            return filteredClientEmp;
```

However, when I inspect the `filteredClientEmp` object, it contains employee's with no birthday and records where the left company value is not equal to null.

The `Client` object has a non virtual list of `Employee`:

```
 public List<Employee> CompanyEmployee { get; set; }
```

Why is this filtering not working?

Comment: Is the `context` clean (`new`)? And what EF version is this?

Comment: So probably this is ef-core and the `Include` is operational because the full `Client` is part of the projection.

Comment: This is EF Core sorry, the context is clean and new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include()` unconditionally loads all child entities. Because you project into an anonymous type with two properties:

- `c`: the client with all its employees
- `CompanyEmployee`: the employees for that client to whom your conditions apply

And then continue to project only `c`, this `c` still includes all employees. You need to overwrite `c`'s CompanyEmployee collection with the filtered collection:

```
.Select(p => { p.c.CompanyEmployee = p.CompanyEmployee; return p.c; })
```

Comment: This is what I thought initially. But `Include`s are normally ignored for projection queries, so there must be something else.

Comment: @Ivan what do you mean? That `c.CompanyEmployee` should be `null` in the `Select()`?

Comment: I mean (1) The `Include` should have no effect because of the projection (`Select`) (2) Assignment `p.c.CompanyEmployee = ...` normally should not be needed because the collection should already has been assigned and populated during the `ToList` call (by EF navigation property fixup). But it could help though :) The whole technique is a hack hence may fail for several reasons.

Comment: @Ivan (1): (assuming EF6): unless lazy loading is enabled, you need to `Include()` entities that you actually want returned from the query. (2) The assignment is needed because the included collection needs to be filtered. Or am I missing something? Does EF Core do this differently? I haven't used it that intensively yet.

Comment: Whichever version it is, the `Include` should just be removed from the query. Relationship fixup will populate the filtered collections. Lazy loading isn't involved because the collection isn't `virtual` or because this is ef-core. Bit frustrating that OP doesn't seem to be stand-by after asking a question...

Comment: @Gert so you're saying that a navigation property used in a `Where()` will also load and populate that navigation property? Then still, the `Include()` doesn't hurt, right? And the collection property still won't be filtered. Or I'm missing something the both of you are trying to tell, or I misinterpreted the OP's requirements.

Comment: Yes, that's what EF does. If this is ef-core I think the `Include` does "hurt", i.e. is not a no-op as it would be in ef6.

Comment: I had to ToList p.CompanyEmployee but this works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in:

```
.Select(pro => pro.c).ToList();
```

You are not returning the clients with the list of employees filtered in:

```
CompanyEmployee = c.CompanyEmployee.Where(e => e.EmployeeBirthday != null && e.EmpType == 2 && e.LeftCompany == null)
```

In fact that property if the anonymous type is not used at all. Instead you are returning the filtered list of all clients which:

1) Have the specified HrPersonId and

2) Have **at least one employee** with a birthday, an employee type of 2 and have not left the company.

To return the Clients with the filtered list your final Select should look something like:

```
.Select(pro => { pro.c.CompanyEmployee = pro.CompanyEmployee; return pro.c; })
```